# Update a nested array in a nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nested-lists

I am trying to update using this route.

```
router.put("/:id", async(req,res)=>{

  try {
   const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
      
        $push: {
          clients:{ 
          client_name: req.body.client_name,
          client_Username: req.body.client_Username,
          client_Password: req.body.client_Password,
          documents : [ 
           {
            name : req.body.docName,
            descritption : req.body.docDescription,
            doc_upload : req.body.doc_upload,
          }
        ]
    }
        }

        },{new:true})
        res.status(200).json(updateUser);
      }
     catch(err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });
```

Once the function founds the id it updates client_name, client_Username and client_password without any issue.

My problem is when I try to update the nested array documents with a name/description and doc_upload. I am not able to do that.

What’s wrong ? How to do it please ?

Comment: Have you tried arrayFilters?

Comment: What are you currently getting and what's the expected result for the `documents` array? Right now, you're creating a new array with one object each time containing the `name`, `description`, and `doc_upload` properties with the values from `req.body`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to separate the updates:

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { client_name, client_Username, client_Password } = req.body;
    const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      {
        $push: {
          clients: {
            client_name,
            client_Username,
            client_Password,
          },
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        id,
        'clients.client_name': client_name,
        'clients.client_Username': client_Username,
      },
      {
        $push: {
          'clients.$.documents': {
            name: req.body.docName,
            descritption: req.body.docDescription,
            doc_upload: req.body.doc_upload,
          },
        },
      }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updateUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```